# replacing single character in sed

Tags: sed, text-processing

I currently have a list of grades and Im trying to change all of the grades to A's, I cant work out how to use the sed to only change the grades as it keeps changing the first characters and things like that. I tried sed /s/.$/A/' but that only adds an A at the end of the string.
List:

```
> Steve maths A
>     Steve english C
>     Steve physics E
>     Jane maths A
>     Jane English B
>     Jane physics F
>
```

Thanks

Comment: Check your sed command.  It actually works if you properly use a single quote on the front and omit the `/` before `s`.

Comment: There may be a possibility of spaces after the  grade..

Comment: the command im trying is cat a.txt | sed 's/[A-Z]$/A/'
Still not working though

Comment: did you try `sed 's/[A-Z] *$/A/' a.txt`?

Comment: `I currently have a list of grades and Im trying to change all of the grades to A's` - study much harder :-). You probably just have white space at the end of each line but you may alternatively have control-Ms as provided absolutely free by Microsoft when using their products. Try running dos2unix on your file before running sed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below. I used `[A-Z]$` so that it won't change the  `>` symbol in the last line to `A` . Think there may be some spaces present after the grade. In that case, you could use `sed 's/[A-Z] *$/A/' file`

```
$ sed 's/[A-Z]$/A/' file
> Steve maths A
>     Steve english A
>     Steve physics A
>     Jane maths A
>     Jane English A
>     Jane physics A
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not `sed` but this `awk` may do, it replaces last field with an `A`

```
awk '{$NF="A"}1' file
> Steve maths A
> Steve english A
> Steve physics A
> Jane maths A
> Jane English A
> Jane physics A
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it also strips all indentation and condenses all other white space to a single blank char.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run `dos2unix` or similar on your file first but then:

```
$ sed 's/[[:upper:]][[:space:]]*$/A/' file
> Steve maths A
>     Steve english A
>     Steve physics A
>     Jane maths A
>     Jane English A
>     Jane physics A
>
```

will work.